no member named 'join' in namespace 'fmt'
I am trying to run userver on macOS. I am following this tutorial  https://userver.tech/d3/da9/md_en_2userver_2tutorial_2build.html
My Boost version is 1.85.0 and clang - 13.0.0
My actions:
git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/userver-framework/service_template.git && \
git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/userver-framework/userver.git service_template/third_party/userver && \
cd service_template

brew install $(cat third_party/userver/scripts/docs/en/deps/macos.md | tr '\n' ' ')


make build-release && \
make service-start-release

I have an error:
49_USERVER/01_tutorial/service_template/third_party/userver/universal/src/yaml_config/impl/validate_static_config.cpp:59:44: error: no member named 'join' in namespace 'fmt'
        enum_value.As<std::string>(), fmt::join(ordered_enum_values, ", ")));
                                      ~~~~~^
/Users/mascai/root_folder/dev/projects/49_USERVER/01_tutorial/service_template/third_party/userver/universal/src/yaml_config/impl/validate_static_config.cpp:71:33: error: no member named 'join' in namespace 'fmt'
  return fmt::format("{}", fmt::join(object | boost::adaptors::map_keys, ", "));
                           ~~~~~^


We con't have enough information. Did you use a package manager to add the fmt library to your project for example?

@PepijnKramer yes, I have added fmt package with help of this command: ```brew install $(cat third_party/userver/scripts/docs/en/deps/macos.md | tr '\n' ' ')


have you included fmt/ranges.h? https://fmt.dev/11.0/api/#range-and-tuple-formatting

@AlanBirtles yes, sure

I'm experiencing the same issue with clang 15.0.0 (and Boost 1.86.0). I tried adding #include <fmt/ranges.h> to all files where the error appeared but ran into
service_template/third_party/userver/universal/include/userver/utils/strong_typedef.hpp:455:13: note: partial specialization matches [with T = userver::components::impl::ComponentNameFromInfo, Char = char] struct fmt::formatter<
/opt/homebrew/include/fmt/ranges.h:517:8: note: partial specialization matches [with R = userver::components::impl::ComponentNameFromInfo, Char = char] struct formatter<

I created an issue at GitHub: https://github.com/userver-framework/userver/issues/689

There's a bug in libfmt 11. Revert libfmt to <11.
See https://bugs.gentoo.org/942306 for explanation and alternatives.

For me it now works out of the box, either because they fixed the issue (https://github.com/userver-framework/userver/issues/689#issuecomment-2424227978) or because some dependency's problem disappeared.
